# What are these cream plastic-like blobs on my circuit board?

Tags: pcb, repair

I see these white/cream colored blobs all over the board (I've surrounded them with red rectangles in the image above), something which I've never encountered before. They're plastic like in texture, deforming with small amounts of pressure applied to them. Does anybody have any idea what these might be, and whether or not they're indicative of some kind of failure?

[image: Circuit board with blobs highlighted] [image] [image]

### Context

My motorcycle's EFI control unit is complaining about not getting enough supply voltage (it is, I've checked the input pins) after breaking down recently (and this is now preventing the bike from starting up), so I figured this electronics degree must be worth something, right?

Hoping it might be as simple as a blown capacitor or damaged track, I removed the control unit from my bike and pried off the metal cover covering the pcb, which was attached with some kind of waterproof sealant (somehow without damaging the circuit board myself). The image below is what I found myself presented with.

Also, if anybody happens to notice anything obviously wrong in the circuit board above, I'd appreciate very much if you could post a comment and let me know!

*p.s.* The supply rails on either side of the board measured ~5mV across with the bike's ignition turned on (what the hell? basically nothing). The Infineon CPU seems to be rated for 3.3V of supply voltage... so one thing I tried was putting a small 3V DC supply in parallel across the rails, hoping it might stop complaining about having low voltage (it didn't), was this stupid? Yes it was.

Comment: The "supply rails" are probably both connected to ground. All you did was short out your 3V supply.

Comment: The blobs look an awful like RTV silicone sealant.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I guess it was a stupid thing to do. I figured they were supply rails from their shape and the + symbol next to one of them, and since they are often displayed in these positions on circuit diagrams.
@DwayneReid My thoughts exactly! I just don't understand why it would be all over the place like this?
Also, please let me know if I've done something silly in my question, or if it is just a silly question itself. I'd rather avoid attracting downvotes :(

Comment: Downvotes usually mean you should have done more research prior to asking. Maybe. Someone might think it is indeed a silly question. Hard to tell - downvoters are supposed to at least explain their actions in the comment section.

Comment: Damn. I promise I have been googling "PCB white blobs" (and etc.) for the past several hours :) Even a friend working in circuit design had no idea.

Comment: Such repair questions are closed.

Comment: ...But it's a question asking whether or not such a thing is a commonly seen defect when repairing PCBs, while I'm in the process of trying to repair said PCB. I don't see why it would be considered irrelevant to repair.

Comment: @dext0rb: They are not. See the many meta discussions. There is no obligation to explain your votes whatsoever.

Comment: @user31131  There seem to be 2 questions in this post.  (1) *What are the blobs on the PCB?*  That question wouldn't be off-topic.  (2) *Repair of the motorcycle EFI.*  Repair questions are usually off-topic, unless the O.P. has a good understanding of the underlying design (which is rare).  In general, the StackExchange's Q&A format isn't well suited for case-by-case troubleshooting, in my opinion.

Comment: The question is about what the blobs are on the PCB. I just felt there was value in explaining the context of the situation, and mentioning that I would appreciate any comments about the state of the PCB in general, since I am not experienced in PCB repair (though it was not intended as a separate question or part of the main question at all).

Comment: @NickAlexeev: More importantly it doesn't match the sites stated goal of compiling a library of Q&A that will help later visitors.

Comment: @user31131  I too am curious as to what the blobs are for.  The title of the question is fine.  The pictures are excellent.  But the text of the question starts with "*My motorcycle's EFI control unit is complaining [...]*", and two-thirds of the text talks about your repair woes.  So, it doesn't surprise me that some EE.SEers see this as a repair question.

Comment: @user31131  The same title and images would fly better on EE.SE if the structure of the text were: "*What's the purpose of these blobs on the PCB?  The PCB comes from a motorcycle EFI.  (By the way, the reason why I'm looking at the PCB is because it's malfunctioning.)*"

Comment: @user31131  You're welcome.  Few more pointers.  (1) Repair questions may fly better in the [EE.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).  The dialog format in the chat works better for troubleshooting.  You'll be able to participate in the chat once you have 20 reputation.  It will not take you long to get that.  (2) There is a specialized stack for motor vehicle maintenance and repair [Mechanics.SE](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I know the comments section turned into a learning experience, but I'm still interested in the original question regarding the (probably) sealant on the board. Does anyone have any application notes for something like this? My google fu isn't handling this very well.

Comment: Nothing on the board seems patently bad. Have you checked the regulators output under load? A nice 50 to 100 ohm resistor on the regulator output, measuring the voltage across it would help knowing if the regulators are actually providing the right voltage inside the control box.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Besides the blurb at the end, I don't see how OP is actually asking anything about fixing this device. Crux of the question is patently: *What is this substance?*  I'm not going to go argue on meta and I won't post any more here than this: it should be courtesy to explain reasons for downvote. If everyone here really strives for quality like they claim, feedback needs to be provided so that question "quality" improves. Or just continue to alienate people, that's fine too.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks for the comment, I'm having trouble identifying a regulating portion of the circuit, there doesn't seem to be any regulator IC on here and since I can't see the other side of the board it's difficult to follow the traces, maybe I'm missing something obvious? If you mean the regulator/rectifier on the bike for the stator output, that is indeed bad and seems to be the problem that caused damage to the circuit in the first place -- I don't think it produces any output while the engine's off, and I've checked the voltage supply coming into the pins of the circuit are correct.

Comment: @dext0rb: So besides where he is asking about repair he isn't asking for repair? That fits for all repair questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've read @Matt's answer.  The adhesive for holding the components during reflow is usually red in color, it's less runny, and there's usually less of it.  Here's an [example](http://www.ekval.fi/store/product_catalog.php?c=45) of such adhesive.

I've got a different hypothesis.  I would guess that this is a thermally conductive adhesive that's holding something on the other side of the PCB.  It may be improving the thermal conductivity between the PCB and the heat sink (or case).  Notice that this white adhesive occurs mostly around components which are heat-sunk to the PCB.

Comment: Absolutely! I've posted my findings as a comment on the other answer.

Comment: By the way, red doesn't seem to be the only color for SMT assembly glue. Apparently it comes in yellow too: http://www.coprise.com/Heraeus_SMT_adhesive.html

Comment: I found one PCB manufacturer that offers this: http://www.eurocircuits.com/PCB-design-guidelines#heatsinkpaste Basically it's a paste that becomes solid after baking. It's poured thorough vias so on the other side you see those bubbles.

Answer (score 5):

The first picture has pads for a couple  DPAK components that have white stuff around the body pad. It looks like the populated DPAK next to it has the same stuff under the component. There are a couple other places where missing components have white stuff.

I would venture a guess that there are components on both sides of this board, and that is the glue to hold the components in place for reflow. The random dots throughout the board are glue seeping through vias from the other side.

Comment: Excellent!  I wouldn't have thought of that.  I'm guessing that the OP will confirm.

Comment: We have a winner! Sort of.. It's very difficult to look on the other side of the pcb, as it's covered by another metal plate with a very difficult to remove seal. I peeked under the plate and there were no visible components (just some solder joints). However, it looks like some parts of the PCB have been bonded to the metal plate with some type of sealant (possibly thermal paste to use the plate as a heatsink?) and it certainly does look like this is what has been leaking through the vias. Good eye!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience they are blobs of rtv used to seal moisture sensitive low level and/or analog signals against potential moisture and/or condensation.